# Trying to add a Div inside another Div inside another Div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am not sure this is the best way to proceed but I am trying to dynamically create new parts of a form, depending on how much the user needs.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-auto" id="nameEntries">
  <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">Nom</div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="entrees[nom]">
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="addFields()">Ajouter une entrée d'argent</a>
```

I am trying to display this section again dynamically when the user presses the link. Here is the JS

```
function addFields() {
  //creating the divs
  var colDiv = document.createElement("div");
  colDiv.class = "col-auto";
  var inputGroupName = document.createElement("div");
  inputGroupName.class = "input-group mb-2";
  var inputGroupPrepend = document.createElement("div");
  inputGroupPrepend.class = "input-group-prepend";
  var inputGroupText = document.createElement("div");
  inputGroupText.class = "input-group-text";
  var nameNode = document.createTextNode("Name");
  var nameInput = document.createElement("input");
  nameInput.type = "text";
  nameInput.class = "form-control";
  nameInput.name = "entrees" + i + "[name]";
  nameInput.placeholder = "...";
  //appending them to each other

  inputGroupText.appendChild(nameNode);
  inputGroupPrepend.appendChild(inputGroupText);
  inputGroupName.appendChild(inputGroupPrepend);
  inputGroupName.appendChild(nameInput);
  colDiv.appendChild(inputGroupName);
  document.getElementById('nameEntries').appendChild(colDiv);
}
```

I added a picture of what the page looks like. When the user presses "Ajouter une entrée d'argent", another section identical as where the fields are should appear right below.
[Link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM98W.png)

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Hey, Are you looking something like this? https://jsbin.com/loconukisi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addFields() {
  var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  // this is the HTML generated to append to the wrapper div. Don't use the id. You can use data-attributes to identify the columns. Or if you've something unique then you can use that as ID. 
  var outerDiv = $('<div/>').addClass('col-auto').append(
    $('<div/>').addClass('input-group mb-2').append(
      $('<div/>').addClass('input-group-prepend').append(
        $('<div/>').addClass('input-group-text').html('Nom')
      )
    ).append(
      $('<input/>').attr({
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'name'
      }).addClass('form-control')
    )
  );
  wrapper.append(outerDiv);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rowAdder').on('click', addFields);
  addFields();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <!-- Your all the div elements will be added here.  -->
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="rowAdder">Ajouter une entrée d'argent</a>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cloneNode(true)` method to reproduce an existing HTML structure:

```
xyz.appendChild(abc.cloneNode(true))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = document.getElementById('child');
document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(e);
```